# What's complexity of select * from table order by id desc limit a, b?

Tags: mysql

I'm displaying about 1,000,000 records separated by 10 records per page.

```
select * from table order by id DESC limit a, b;
```

In this query `id` is indexed, and `b` is 10.

The querying time is fast when `a` is small, but the time dramatic increased to about 100s when a is near the end of the table. I wonder what's the time complexity of this query? Is it bounded by `O(b)` or `O(a)`?

(I use the Innodb engine)

When a = 200000, The `Explain` said:

```
+----+-------------+--------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+----------+-------+
| id | select_type | table  | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows   | filtered | Extra |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+----------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | status | index | NULL          | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL | 200001 |   653.99 |       |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+----------+-------+
```

Comment: Look at your `EXPLAIN`

Comment: Look at your `EXPLAIN`, under the `rows` title.

Comment: So it means the complexity is `O(a)`, right?

Comment: `LIMIT a, b` is the same as `LIMIT b OFFSET a`, so first the index has to be read sequentially and `a` values skipped (assuming that `id` is unique), then `b` values read from the index and then `b` rows retrieved from the table. Since this is InnoDB (and again assuming that the clustered index is on `id`), the 2nd operation is skipped and the 3rd is done together on the clustered index (e.g. the table).

Comment: So, the "complexity" is roughly `O(a) + O(b)`, without taking into consideration pages, blocks or index length.